# Custom EditorTemplate not being used in MVC4 for DataType.Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm upgrading an MVC3 application to MVC4 using the [instructions from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806). Everything went fairly smoothly - except a few of my date model properties are now rendering differently. For example, one of these properties is defined in the viewmodel like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[RegularExpression(@"([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])...",
    ErrorMessage = "Format is mm/dd/yyyy")]
[FormatHint("mm/dd/yyyy")]
[InputSize("small")]
public string Date { get; set; }
```

Before upgrading to MVC4, this would be rendered via calling `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)` which would use a custom EditorTemplate - the `String.cshtml` template (since it's a string!). I have some custom data annotations that formats the html so it utilizes a field layout, jQueryUI, and twitter Bootstrap on the client side. The validation is done via jquery validation unobtrusive. Anyhow, this is how it previously rendered:

[image: date editor]

Now that I'm using MVC4, the `String.cshtml` editor template is not being called for this property any longer. It renders like this (in Chrome using the HTML5 editor stuff, I assume):

[image: date editor mvc4]

The `input` element looks pretty much the same - all the jQuery validation bits are in there - the only difference seems to be the `type` attribute is now `type="date"`, where before it was `type="text"`.

I'd like to continue using the `String.cshtml` EditorTemplate for this datatype. I'm thinking there might be a data annotation that I can put on the ViewModel property to provide a TemplateHint for `@Html.EditorFor(...)`. If not this, I'd like to know the custom EditorTemplate that I can write to hijack MVC4's formatting (I've already tried `DateTime.cshtml` - it's not being called either).  If not either of those, then I'm open to suggestions on how to get my property rendering like it used to.

Comment: It seems as your second pic shows the `datepicker()` called twice with two different UI, are you sure about duplicate call of `datepicker()`? by the way I use `datepicker` from jQueryUI in MVC4 without any problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `MVC4`, the used template is determinated from :

1. The `UIHintAttribute` if any
2. The `DataTypeAttribute` if any
3. The type of the property

In `MVC3`, the `DataTypeAttribute` was not used.

Your property has a

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

so the template `Date.cshtml` is used. If it does not exists, default rendering is executed.

You have two options to resolve your problem :

1. Add a `UIHint("String")` on your property, or
2. Rename your editor template from `String.cshtml` to `Date.cshtml`

Comment: you saved my life.

"Your property has a
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
so the template Date.cshtml is used."

Comment: Thank you, the combination of `DataType(DataType.Date)` and `UIHint("String")` helped me implement the jquery datepicker without the html5 datepicker.